# Code snippets from .NET Agent not showing in Elastic APM

Tags: .net, elastic-apm

We're using the .NET agent (1.4) and Elastic ECE 7.6.
Activating the APM server and instrumenting our application was quite easy.
Everything seems to work up until the point where it needs to show the code snippet related to a particular span.

Below an example of what I'm looking for from a Node application:

[image]

**My question:**

Is this not yet included in the .NET agent, or is there additional configuration necessary to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this not yet included in the .NET agent, or is there additional configuration necessary to get this working?

This is not yet included in the .NET Agent unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Is it somewhere on the roadmap?

Comment: Or a feature request that I can track maybe?

Comment: It's currently not on the roadmap. You can open an issue in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-dotnet/issues/new/choose